# How to add Speed while clicking a button?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local function onMouseClicked()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local clicks = player:WaitForChild('leaderstats'):WaitForChild('Clicks')
    local rebirths = player:WaitForChild('leaderstats'):WaitForChild('Rebirths')
    clicks.Value = clicks.Value +1
    if rebirths .Value > 0 then
        clicks.Value = clicks.Value + rebirths.Value
    end
    player.WalkSpeed = 16 + clicks.Value
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onMouseClicked)
```

I tried to make some code if i click the button it will add speed.

Answer (score 1):

To add speed to the player while clicking a button, you can add the code below to the onMouseClicked function:

```
player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed + (clicks.Value + rebirths.Value)
```

Thank you!